# Compiler refuses to convert Window to FrameworkElement

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, frameworkelement

Am I going crazy? Or is it the compiler?

I have:

```
Window w = new Window();
```

When I'm trying to use with a function that expects a `FrameworkElement`, the compiler complains:

> cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Window' to
>   'System.Windows.FrameworkElement'

When I'm trying to do `w.Show()`, it complains:

> 'System.Windows.Window' does not contain a definition for 'Show'
>   and no extension method 'Show' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Windows.Window' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

BUT, when I do intellisense "Go to definition", I can see that `Window` is a subclass of `ContentControl`, which is a subclass of `FrameworkElement`, and I can see the `Show()` method.

I even tried `System.Windows.Window w = new System.Windows.Window()`

What's going on?

**EDIT**: code sample (if it helps):

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        private void SomeMethod()
        {
            Window w = new Window();
            w.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**: "CSProj" ItemGroup:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Strange. Can you post small sample replicating the issue. Working fine at my end.

Comment: Indeed, strange. In the same project in another file this works fine. I reduced the file to bare minimum: a class declaration, a private method, and `Window w = new Window()` followed by `w.Show()`

Comment: Did you check if you have the same references included? I'm not sure if it is an extension method.

Comment: Same project, thus same references, I guess.

Comment: Check your `usings` at the top.

Comment: @Steve, I have and reduced them to bare minimum.

Comment: I would really do what Rohit said from the beginning. Post the actual code.

Comment: @Steve - updated the question with a code sample

Comment: Can not duplicate your problem with your code sample.

Comment: @MarkHall, I know... it must have something to do with a VS Project/Solution. I just can't imagine what.

Comment: @NewDev, can you go to the csproj file and get the "ItemGroup" section that contains the "Reference Include=xxxx" and amend your question?  No promises, but it helps clarify at least the first level of inquiry.

Comment: @NewDev, looks clean.  Please add this to your code: Window w = new Window(); var t = w.GetType(); Debugger.Break() and inspect 't' and tell us what you get...

Comment: @GarryVass, RuntimeType: Name = "Window" FullName = "System.Windows.Window"